# Blueimp file upload resize and Chrome?

Tags: jquery-plugins, image-resizing, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

The example for client-side resizing at [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Client-side-Image-Resizing) disables resizing for Chrome, with this comment:

```
// Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
// which actually support image resizing, but fail to
// send Blob objects via XHR requests:
```

Chrome is an increasingly important browser; is there any way around this which I've not come across?  I can (and do) resize on the server after upload but I would prefer client-side.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this limitation might be obsolete.
There are two related bugs in Android's issue tracker, which are marked as "obsolete":
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22441
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36524

I haven't tested it, but would be glad if someone could confirm that it's working now and on which Android version.

Comment: what about resize in Android and Opera? This is really important.